# Why my screenshot saved in text format?

Tags: screenshot, text

I took a screenshot using shift + Print Screen Key. It is saved in the Pictures folder as a text document and couldn't view the image.

The extension is still .png but the image viewer couldn't open it. Thumbnail looks like a text file.

Update: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1322640/edit) and add the new information. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: This ins't an answer to your problem but an alternative solution instead. Install Flameshot and update the keyboard shortcuts to your liking. https://snapcraft.io/install/flameshot/ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that my computer was running out of memory(Not even 100kb free space) because of a python script I was executing. I freed up some memory and it solved the problem.

Comment: Good troubleshooting!